# view PDF in UIWebView

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview

The "supporting files" folder of my app contains a document named `test.pdf`.
Trying to view the pdf file with the following code in `ViewDidLoad` displays an empty UIWebView:

```
NSString *testPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *testURL = [NSURL URLWithString:testPath];
NSURLRequest *testRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:testURL];

UIWebView *documentWebView;

documentWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 24, 300, 400)];

[documentWebView loadRequest:testRequest];

[self.view addSubview:documentWebView];
```

Can anyone tell me why the PDF isn't displayed in the web view? Thanks.

Comment: Is that pdf file added to your xcode?

Comment: Yes, in the "supporting files" folder.

Comment: Try deleting and adding again. Also check Target -> "Build Phases" -> "copy bundle Resources" and make sure it is present

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried deleting and adding again and the document is listed in Build Phases but no joy.

Comment: Does that resolve your issue or you are still facing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
NSURL *testURL = [NSURL URLWithString:testPath];
```

needs to be:

```
NSURL *testURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:testPath];
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed and very well spotted. That's been driving me nuts for hours. =)